# Insert value into column gained from join on two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How would I insert a value into a column based upon the result of a simple join condition on two tables?

I have managed to do this for an UPDATE, but not an INSERT because all the values are comma-separated together.

Comment: Stop having comma separated values in your fields?

Comment: sample data / code will help

Comment: @podiluska insert into table (col1,col2...) values (x COMMA y COMMA z)......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with expr(a,b) as (
   select t.val, u.val 
    from (values(0,1)) as t(id,val) 
     join (values(0,2)) as u(id,val)
      on t.id = u.id
) insert into table(column) select a as vals from expr union all select b from expr
```

Comment: It's a common table expression (or CTE). When using WITH you identify a name for the result and its columns so you can call it in a following select statement or query.

Comment: This will only work if you are inserting the values into only one column of a table. To insert a tuple you can 'insert into table select a,b from expr' but the table's attributes have to match the columns of the result (types, number of columns, and order of columns).